# Signed integer type and its corresponding unsigned integer type

Tags: c, integer, language-lawyer, conversion-rank

For each signed integer type the Standard guarantees existence of a *corresponding* unsigned integer type. `6.2.5 p6`:

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but
>   different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword `unsigned`
>   ) that uses the same amount of storage (including sign information)
>   and has the same alignment requirements.

The phrase *designated with the keyword `unsigned`* got me confused and I consulted with earlier versions of the Standard to understand if it was presented there. [C89/3.2.1.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.1.2.5) provides exactly the same wording:

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but
>   different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword
>   `unsigned`) that uses the same amount of storage (including sign
>   information) and has the same alignment requirements.

Now consider `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`; `uintmax_t` and `intmax_t`; etc... (which are optional, but in case an implementation defines those types).

**QUESTION:** According to the definition I cited above isn't `uintptr_t` a corresponding unsigned integer type for `intptr_t` and `uintmax_t` is a corresponding unsigned integer type for `intmax_t`?

I'm concerned about it because Usual arithmetic conversion uses the term `6.3.1.8 p1`:

> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type

So I'm trying to understand the semantic of the usual arithmetic conversion applied to, say, `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`.

Comment: These are typedefs, not the actual types.

Comment: @Barmar Most likely, but it is not defined by the Standard AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to 7.20(4) these are typedef names, not the underlying types.

> For each type described herein that the implementation provides,261) `<stdint.h>` shall declare that typedef name and define the associated macros.

And 7.20.1(1) says:

> When typedef names differing only in the absence or presence of the initial u are defined, they shall denote corresponding signed and unsigned types as described in 6.2.5;

So I believe these are required to follow the same default conversion rules as the basic integer types are.

Comment: Can't we make the same assumptions for types defined in `<stddef.h>`?

Comment: I mean that `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t` are `typedef`s.

Comment: Yes, although I don't see what it has to do with the question. These don't come in both signed and unsigned variants.

Answer (score 2):

The header in the Standard "7.20.1.5 Greatest-width integer types" and the description under the header where the two types are described in a pair assume that `uintmax_t` is defined as an unsigned type corresponding to the type `intmax_t`.

Answer (score 2):

The `intN_t` and `uintN_t` fixed width types weren't introduced until C99, so that may be why the standard you're referencing lacks information about them.